# Cross-Browser XML Insert

Tags: ajax, svg, xml-parsing, domparser

I need to insert an XML (svg) file's contents into an html div. For browsers that don't support DOMParser() (IE7 & 8), how can I do this?

It appears that in IE8 I can insert the xml contents as text using innerHTML, but it doesn't render the svg.

My work is online at http://ec2-174-129-62-227.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/ but it may change a little bit as I tweak solutions. **Make sure you click the "Leafy Tree" radio button.** If it's functional, it should work fine in IE9 and chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 and lower doesn't support SVG, so even if you manage to insert the elements it still won't render.

Comment: For some reason I thought svg was supported by IE long, long ago, but  I guess I was wrong. Thanks for straightening me out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [jQuery parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) will serve you better?

Answer (score 0):

Although they won't work for my case, I did find some polyfills that will render something with SVG in older browsers. I particularly like [this one by google](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/). It uses your svg data to actually render a flash version in older internet explorer.